# Feature Branch Artifacts Workflow in CI with SemVer

Tags: python, git-flow, semantic-versioning, twine, setuptools-scm

I have a library (let's call it `my_lib`) and an application (`my_app`) structured in two Python packages where my tool `my_app` requires `my_lib` in the `requirements.txt`. In practice, I often develop a feature in `my_app` where the underlying added functionality is added to `my_lib` and then utilized in `my_app` (to re-use library `my_lib` in another setting).

I develop using **Gitflow** development principle and have a CI stage for both packages in a `feature` branch for both packages (let's call them `feature/my_feature_in_lib` and `feature/my_feature_in_app` for the argument's sake here). In CI, e.g., unit testing and package upload to a (private) PyPI is done.

Of course, I don't want to merge `feature/my_feature_in_lib` into the integration branch of `my_lib` before I properly tested it, which is often done in conjunction with `feature/my_feature_in_app` in CI.

Ideally, I would want `feature/my_feature_in_lib` to create an artifact / package that is then consumed by `my_app` in it's `requirements.txt`. I currently use [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/) for a SemVer-like auto-incrementation of the version number (such as `0.10.1.post1`). However, this scheme can lead to version duplications if working with multiple feature branches in parallel (which is why I currently only create artifacts on the integration branch).

Tools such as [GitVersion](https://gitversion.net/docs/learn/branching-strategies/gitflow/) in the C# world allow for version identifiers that contain feature branch specific identifiers, such as `1.2.3-alpha.feature-a682956d`. However, [PEP-440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) forbids the use of such versioning schemes and twine even rejects such uploads.

What is the optimal way to solve these dependency issues over package-boundaries while maintaining a SemVer-like automatic version incrementation?

Thanks in advance!